# Python 3.3 to exe

Tags: python

Evening,

I have a hangman program with a simple GUI. I need to convert it to an executable file so other people can use it without python installed.

I am aware of cx freeze and I have installed it and I know I need a setup file however I am not sure how to code this and/or make it work. Is there anyone who has a template of script file and how I am supposed to use it?
In my program I have imported two modules random and tkinter. I use python 3.3 32 bit version as well.

Comment: If you're aware of `cx_Freeze`, read its docs and examples. You can also find thousands of more examples in published modules. If you can't understand part of the docs/examples, or you think you understand it but your `setup.py` isn't working, then you'll have a great question to ask